# Application Login not working unless Windows Authentication works in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database set up that is to gather planned vacation time that I need to put on sharepoint asap. It's completely done, except for that the application login is failing for anyone that tries to use it that does not have their corprate login (windows authentication) listed in the security logins folder.

The connection string is fine, as it works properly on my computer and another programmer's computer, but not on my boss's computer. I can also login to sql server using the application login that is listed in the connection string.

I'm using **SQL Server Managment Studio 2008**, the server is **2005**.

**Edit#1:** Further research led to finding this page: http://sql-articles.com/articles/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-login-failed-error-18456/
And my error is state 11. It's listing a windows authentication in the error log even though I specified otherwise.

**Edit#2:** My Connection String is this:

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=ServerName\ThingIdontUnderstand;Database=ReportingDevDB;Trusted_Connection=FALSE;uid=Derp;pwd=qwerty;
```

**Edit#3:** Solved! See comments on this post for answers since I can't answer my own questions yet.

Comment: If your connection string has a username, password, and specifies `Integrated Security=SSPI`, then it actually does windows authentication rather than using the username and password. Some other options in the connection string can lead to a similar issue. In order to positively identify this, you'd have to post the actual connection string (with suitable anonymization).

Comment: My Connection String is:

Driver={SQL Server};Server=ServerName\ThingIdontUnderstand;Database=ReportingDevDB;Trusted_Connection=FALSE;uid=Derp;pwd=qwerty;

Comment: I don't think you need Trust_Connection unless you are using it.  Also, the examples I can find have Trusted_Connection=yes, not true.  I'm not sure FALSE is value.

Comment: Sweet. It seems that changing **FALSE** to **no** did the trick. Not sure if adding in "Integrated_Security=no;" did anything or not.

Answer (score 0):

You check for the version when you connect to the instance through SSMS it will show it beside the server name under Object Explorer. Or just use the query `SELECT @@VERSION`

I would suggest simply creating a corporate windows group and adding those individuals to it, and then simply add this group as a login to your instance of SQL Server.

Comment: It says it's SQL Server 2005.

And I don't want to add 500 accounts to a development server. We're using it real quick because Excel as a database has finally proved how unrelible it is, and the dev server isn't really company approved.